# Locating errors in React.js return JSX statements

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, upgrade, jsx

During upgrading of react version from 0.13 to 15.4 nearly all dependencies are updated. And those changes also include e.g. `react-bootstrap`.

As I know, errors in JSX in return statements are caught by React and in most of the cases I don't have any clues whats going on wrongly. All code seems to be perfectly fine, but I can't see result of component being rendered into actual DOM.

How can I locate components that are causing error in return statements in React/JSX?

Answer (score 0):

One effective way of locating components (parts of return statement) that should work but doesn't is commenting out parts of JSX and refreshing page. If part of missing component appeared, you've commented out `bad` part and now you can investigate it.

You can start with commenting out whole render function and putting random message in return e.g.

```
   render: function() { 
     return (
      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
      );
   }
```